# SQL DISTINCT/GROUP BY not working

Tags: sql, syntax, firebird

Bear with me here, I am very new to SQL. I have the following query written out but the DISTINCT is essentially being negated by my WHERE statement. This is due to the fact that the dates in the table are followed by a time stamp so if there is any difference in the time the line items were put it, it generates a new row.

What would be the best way to have it completely ignore everything after the date so that no new lines are generated due to time stamps? From what I have found, I think this is better achieved using GROUP BY but that seams to always generate an error (most likely me not knowing where to put the aggregate function).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
Select DISTINCT
 so.num AS Ref
,  so.shiptoname AS Recipient_Full_Name
, so.shiptoaddress AS Address_1
, so.shiptocity AS City
, stateconst.name AS State
, so.shiptozip AS Zip
, so.billtoname AS Buyer_Name
, qbclass.name AS Class
, soitem.datescheduledfulfillment AS Fulfillment_Date
From SO
JOIN stateconst
ON so.shiptostateid=stateconst.id
JOIN qbclass
ON so.qbclassid=qbclass.id
JOIN soitem
ON so.id=soitem.soid
WHERE DATESCHEDULEDFULFILLMENT LIKE '2016-05-10%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CAST()` to change the `datetime` data type to a `date` type:

```
Select DISTINCT
 so.num AS Ref
,  so.shiptoname AS Recipient_Full_Name
, so.shiptoaddress AS Address_1
, so.shiptocity AS City
, stateconst.name AS State
, so.shiptozip AS Zip
, so.billtoname AS Buyer_Name
, qbclass.name AS Class
, CAST(soitem.datescheduledfulfillment as date) AS Fulfillment_Date
From SO
JOIN stateconst
ON so.shiptostateid=stateconst.id
JOIN qbclass
ON so.qbclassid=qbclass.id
JOIN soitem
ON so.id=soitem.soid
WHERE CAST(soitem.datescheduledfulfillment as date) = '2016-05-10'
```

Comment: This will certainly work if you don't mind losing the time portion of the `DateScheduledFulfillment` field in your output.

Comment: I have no idea why, but this generates an error as well. Even removing the WHERE will not pull up any data. I copy and pasted to make sure it's right, still error. Does it matter that this is on Firebird?

Comment: Might actually need to `CAST()` on FireBird, I will edit.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I will have to go look up CAST now. :) Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the date in your query output?  Because leaving it out would solve your 'problem':

```
Select DISTINCT
 so.num AS Ref
,  so.shiptoname AS Recipient_Full_Name
, so.shiptoaddress AS Address_1
, so.shiptocity AS City
, stateconst.name AS State
, so.shiptozip AS Zip
, so.billtoname AS Buyer_Name
, qbclass.name AS Class

From SO
JOIN stateconst
ON so.shiptostateid=stateconst.id
JOIN qbclass
ON so.qbclassid=qbclass.id
JOIN soitem
ON so.id=soitem.soid
WHERE DATESCHEDULEDFULFILLMENT LIKE '2016-05-10%'
```